# Why Multivalue Converter is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, converters

I have my Multivalue Converter :

```
class ColorMultiConverter:IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values != null)
            {
                if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                {
                    var customerRating = Int32.Parse(values[0].ToString());
                    var customerName = values[1].ToString();
                    if (customerName == "RaOne" && customerRating > 7)
                    {
                        return "Blue";
                    }
                }
                else
                    return "Yellow";

            }
            return "Red";
        }
```

In XAML , I am binding them as:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CustomerRating,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}">-->
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource colorMultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="CustomerRating"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Customername"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

But my Colors are not getting reflected on grid row!!

**Edit 1:**

Background is of type Brush ,then How is the following Code fine ?? This Works as expected though returning string !!!

```
    class ColorConverter:IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                int colorValue = Int32.Parse(value.ToString());

                if (colorValue < 7)
                {
                    return "Blue";
                }
                return "Red";
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CustomerRating,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}">
```

Comment: Is underlying source class containing property `CustomerRating` implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes @RohitVats. Strangely it's working with Converters but not MultiValue Converter

Comment: Try debugging your converter; that way you can find out what the parameters actually contain and see what’s going wrong.

Comment: @poke, I can See the converter is returning the values, but for some reason , not getting bound to XAML

Comment: @Simsons - I have seen some strange corners where `IValueConverter` works but doesn't work with `IMultiValueConverter`. Mutlivalue converters need to return same type as that of target property. Try the answer i have posted and see if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background is of type `Brush` but you are returning `String` from converter. Return brush instance instead:

```
return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

Replace all other instances to return `SolidColorBrush`.

---

**UPDATE**

I have seen some strange corners where `IValueConverter` works but doesn't work with `IMultiValueConverter`. Multi-value converters need to return same type as that of target property.

Even when you bind `Width` with IValueConverter and return 100 from it, it will work fine. But try returning `100` from IMultiValueConverter, it won't work unless you changed it to `100.0` because width is of type double.

I guess with IValueConverter type conversion is handled by WPF binding engine but not the case with IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks This Works. But returning String just works fine with Single Conveters (I mean Just Converters). How?Just Curious

Comment: Ok , Just Saw Ur Comment on my question. That Clarify. Thanks

Comment: Very valuable information. Previously met with the this problem, but the solution is not known.

Comment: @Anatoliy - Yeah I was stumbled too. I tried to search for any related article over net but couldn't trace any.